# How do I compare two lists and return 4 categories lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two lists have the same properties and I want to compare the data between them, I need three list shown in the view

1. `NewlyAdded` Employee (Done)
2. `Deleted` Employee (Done)
3. `Common` Employee (Done)
4. **Updated Employee** (Don't know how)

I have make the first 3 lists but I don't know how I can get the updated data Then I can deploy the changes to the `destEmps` so anyone can help me?

```
public class srsEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
    public Nullable<system.datetime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<system.datetime> BOD { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual srsDepartment srsDepartment { get; set; }
}

public class destEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
    public Nullable<system.datetime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<system.datetime> BOD { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual destDepartment destDepartment { get; set; }
}
```

And these are the queries I used to get 3 lists:

```
var Common = destEmps.Where(n => srsEmps.Any(o => o.EmpCode == n.EmpCode)).ToList();
var Deleted = srsEmps.Where(o => !destEmps.Any(n => n.EmpCode == o.EmpCode)).ToList();
var NewlyAdded = destEmps.Where(n => !srsEmps.Any(o => o.EmpCode == n.EmpCode)).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you please describe what _exactly_ you want to achieve and what have you already tried?

Comment: This kind of tracking should be done in the DBMS, not the Programm. All you really need is to add a "LastModified" date. Have a Trigger or similar value automatically set it. Maybe you could also work with Rowversion, but that is better suited to avoid update race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Updated =
            from d in destEmps
            join c in srsEmployee
            on c.Id equals d.Id
            where d.Name != c.Name || d.EmpCode != c.EmpCode ..........
            select d;

 foreach(var element in destEmps)
        {
            var oldValue = srsEmployee.First(t => t.Id == element.Id);
            element.Name = oldValue.Name;
            .....
        }
```

Comment: that is works well, so how I can deploy the changes to the destEmps ?

Comment: The destEmps has new values, which changes you want to apply to them?

Comment: i want to make destEmps has the same data that srsEmps has.

Comment: Make a foreach loop over destEmps and change each property by srsEmployee's value

Comment: sorry i'm beginner and make like this tasks to learn, so can you explain to me by the code please ?

Comment: Don't shy, we are here to help each other. I updated my answer. Check it now.

Comment: .First is used to find equivalent element (based on Id) in the orher list

Comment: yeah i got it, so if i have a button in index page and this button called the code of foreach loop you had wrote how i could make this? i want the code inside index page . right ?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Where you declared destEmps and srsEmployee?

Comment: i declared destEmps and srsEmployee in Index()

Comment: Make them Global in order to edit them inside your button-click event

Comment: Ok and make another public method for example Deploy() and make the button calls it?

Comment: i can't make them Global.

Comment: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property

Comment: You can make an static class and put these two lists inside it as static properties

Comment: if i want to copy all data from srsEmps to destEmps not only based on id what i can de in foreach loop ?

Comment: After updating existing items, find not existing ones with Except function and then use Addrange function to add them to second list

Comment: they are not the same type to use AddRange

Comment: Foreach element, create a new object of second type and set each property one by one

Comment: how i can copy also the id although it is IDENTITY?

Comment: You cant. When there is two records with same id, it means you should update instead of copy.

Comment: and if i have record in one srsEmps and want to add it to destEmps with the same id what i will do ?

Comment: You can add them, just add as the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to generate Hashes of Employee class by using all it's properties, then the elements with same Id but different Hashes will be the elements that got updated.

You can generate a hash using the accepted answer from this link [Generate hash of object consistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393467/generate-hash-of-object-consistently)

P.S. I think you should use the same class for Source and Destination list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create an Equals method in your Employee class, and then use that to compare

```
public bool Equals(Employee other)
{
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do your equality test here.
        return (this.ID = other.ID &&
                this.Name = other.Name);
        // etc...
    }
}
```

You can then use it to find all the items in one where the other list contains an item that is equal.